# Trouble with CyanogenMod local_manifest

Tags: android, building, cyanogenmod

When using the commands breakfast  (in this case, hlte (samsung galaxy note 3)), or brunch hlte, it searches for dependencies to build the OS.

I am trying to list different repos to sync from so it doesn't overwrite my changes when it comes to doing another repo sync. You can view my local manifest here: https://github.com/DXC0/local_manifests/blob/master/roomservice.xml

Basically, the point is to replace the default ones with custom ones of the same nature.

When I try to build, it loops while looking for dependencies (seen here: http://pastebin.com/4UtesjJr)

TL;DR

It constantly looks for dependencies and never exits the loop.
I've seen others do this without removing the dependencies from cm.dependencies and it baffles me to say the least.

EDIT:
going to try ubuntu version 12.04 with a fresh repo. Others aren't experiencing this so it must be something on my side :/ Please feel free to tell me I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like the following in your local manifest:

```
<remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_device_samsung_hlte" />
```

This removes the existing project without having to remove it from default.xml and allows your local_manifest to sync your custom repo. Make sure you place it before your custom repo.

Comment: I've tried, it comes back with "fatal: remove-project element specifies non-existent project: CyanogenMod/android_device_samsung_hlte"

Comment: Problem is: it's not declared in the default.xml so it can't be removed. It just gets added automatically when building

Comment: @user3398918: No, I don't think that was the problem. Local manifest files can definitely remove projects, but the files are read in alphabetical order so the name of the file with the `<remove-project>` element must come after the file that adds the project. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374949/android-cyanogenmod-building-remove-project-from-roomservice-xml.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use roomservice.xml for your custom repositories. That local manifest is amended by breakfast/brunch. You can remove repositories from there, but it's best to create a separate manifest for additional repositories. You can have multiple local manifests in that directory, named however you like. I would restore the default contents for the hlte device and kernel to that file first.

Once you have hlte syncing properly using the default repositories, leave roomservice.xml alone and instead use git to manage additional repositories. For instance:

```
cd [android-top]/device/samsung/hlte
git remote add dxc0 git@github.com:DXC0/android_device_samsung_hlte.git -t cm-11.0
git fetch dxc0
git checkout dxc0/cm-11.0
```

where `[android-top]` is the top of your android source tree. Now, you can play around with your own device HEAD. To build, type

```
brunch hlte
```

from the top of your android tree.

As a heads-up, when you run `repo sync`, it will leave your custom HEAD and go back to CM's default. You can easily re-checkout your own tree with `git checkout dxc0/cm-11.0`. To revert to CM's device tree: `git checkout github/cm-11.0`. If you make changes to hlte, sync them to your github account with `git push dxc0 HEAD:cm-11.0`.